# Xcode C project - linker command failed

Tags: c, xcode

The problem is as follows.

I am trying to add two simple .obj files to my project. I have added a header file and I can see that obj is valid as Ttime structure, which is a part of obj is working. However, whenever I try to execute any function I get this error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_printRES", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g5oJ.jpg)

Comment: "add"? How? You should link against, not add. As seen from the screenshot, you have just added them as sources.

Comment: This should be the problem.. I just don't know how to link .obj files. Could you give me some suggestion or a link?